# How to Set SMTP Client in POSTAL MVC not in WEB.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, postal, asp.net-mail

i have a problem when using POSTAL MVC in my Project. My hosting services company requires me to set smtp client config in code not in web config.

How to do that ?

I hope someone can give me a solution

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. There is no reference on the official Postal documentation, nor an How-to.
So here goes one:

1. Create the SmtpClient instance with the custom configuration
2. Create an Postal.EmailService instance using the constructor which takes 2 arguments (ViewEngineCollection, Func «SmtpClient»)
3. Now you can send the email using the custom SmtpClient configuration by calling emailService.

Here goes a complete sample code:

```
dynamic email = new Email("Example");
email.To = "webninja@example.com";
email.FunnyLink = DB.GetRandomLolcatLink();

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.pt", "somepassword");
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Port = 25;
client.EnableSsl = false;

Postal.EmailService emailService = new Postal.EmailService(new ViewEngineCollection(), () => client);

emailService.Send(email);
```

Comment: `ViewEngineCollection` is not a valid parameter to that ctor, and you do nothing to explain what it's supposed to be.

Comment: I don't know what ctor means? I have the above code working on a MVC 5 Controller class

Comment: ctor is a well known abbreviation for constructor. And, my apologies, I don't know why it didn't accept it earlier, but it did now. You are just short of a `new`, which I have added for you.

Comment: My bad. I think I never saw that abbreviation. Thanks for your editing.

Comment: A little late to the party, but I've used this code and get the error: "The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string.".  Has something changed with this approach or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: EmailService emaiService = new EmailService(ViewEngines.Engines, () => client);emaiService.SendAsync(email);

Comment: It shows me this error -> "Email view not found for WeeklyEmail. Locations searched:" ... That view is WeeklyEmail is working well when I use it directly through the web.config settings. But it can't find it this way. It doesn't even list anything in the locations searched!

Comment: @Amitesh im getting the same error. were you able to resolve it??

Answer (score 1):

To Add to Rafael's answer. If you use

```
Postal.EmailService emailService = new Postal.EmailService(new ViewEngineCollection(), () => client);
```

you might get this error: `Email view not found for [name for he email template]. Locations searched` because `new Postal.EmailService(new ViewEngineCollection(), () => client)` creates emailService with empty view engine. Use `ViewEngines.Engines` inplace of `new ViewEngineCollection()` (as sugested by @Houssam Hamdan in comment above) to use razor view engine.

Complete line:

```
Postal.EmailService emailService = new Postal.EmailService(ViewEngines.Engines, () => client);
```