# Email view not found for 'model' in Postal.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-5, postal

I am using Postal.MVC5 in my ASP MVC5 project. Initially i had my smtp configuration in web.config so this piece of code was working just fine and was able to send email successfully.

```
public async Task<ActionResult>SendEmail(EmployeeViewModel emailModel)
{
  string _errorMessage;

  emailModel.To = "john@outlook.com";
  emailModel.Subject = "Test Subject";
  emailModel.Message = "Test Message";

  await emailModel.SendAsync();

  return Json(new {ErrorMessage = _errorMessage});
}
```

Now, i need to setup Smtpclient during runtime and followed steps shown in this stackoverflow post: [How to Set SMTP Client in POSTAL MVC not in WEB.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837478/how-to-set-smtp-client-in-postal-mvc-not-in-web-config)

```
public async Task<ActionResult>SendEmail(EmployeeEmailViewModel emailModel)
{
  string _errorMessage;

  emailModel.To = "john@outlook.com";
  emailModel.Subject = "Test Subject";
  emailModel.Message = "Test Message";

  //new code
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.test.com");
  client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("secretId", "notSecretPassword");
  client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  client.Port = 111;
  client.EnableSsl = true;

  Postal.EmailService emailService = new EmailService(new ViewEngineCollection(), () => client);
  await emailService.SendAsync(emailModel);

  return Json(new {ErrorMessage = _errorMessage});
}
```

Now this code throws an error something like this:
    **System.Exception: Email view not found for EmployeeEmailViewModel. Locations searched: 
      at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.CreateView(String viewName, ControllerContext controllerContext) 
      at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName)**

I do have 'EmployeeEmailViewModel' view in ~/Views/Emails/EmployeeEmailViewModel.cshtml .

Any idea why i am getting this error message or how i can resolve it?
Thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: Instead of editing your question to provide an answer, you should submit the solution as an actual answer.

Comment: @SamAxe you right, i will fix that.

Comment: Anyone who run into this issue, this is how i resolved it.**

    Postal.EmailService emailService = new EmailService(ViewEngines.Engines,() 
    => client);
  
In Web.config, leave from value in smtp attribute within <system.net>
    <smtp from="fromTest@outlook.com"></smtp>
    
    
If someone knows how to set MailMessage from value from code behind, then we don't need to do this on web.config.